ERROR: Can't start DAQ (-1) - Error opening adapter [SNORT]
When I have used command snort -c C:\Snort\etc\snort.conf -A console -i eth0 in cmd I got
this error
Also I've checked this question, but it didn't help me, because after removing wpcap.dll and Packet.dll and reinstalling Npcap, I got error "Don't have entry point"
Is there something specific in this error? And how to solve it?

I've found solution! Just on columns 159 - 162 in snort.conf make some changes. More you can find out from file README.daq which is located in 'doc' folder
